# Spree - Generator command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I am new to Spree and Rails and have been following the developer guide (http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/extensions_tutorial.html)
on spree commerce to build a new extension, but with no success.

When I do the following in my Spree extension director,

```
rails g migration add_sale_price_to_spree_variants sale_price:decimal
```

I get

```
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/acts_as_list-0.2.0/lib/acts
_as_list.rb:18:in `insert': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base (NameError
)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/acts_as_list-0
.2.0/lib/acts_as_list.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_
ext/kernel_require.rb:64:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_
ext/kernel_require.rb:64:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spree_core-2.0
.4/lib/spree/core.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_
ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_
ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_
ext/kernel_require.rb:122:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/spree_layered_pricing/lib/spree_layered_pricing/engine.rb:
3:in `<class:Engine>'
        from C:/Sites/spree_layered_pricing/lib/spree_layered_pricing/engine.rb:
2:in `<module:SpreeLayeredPricing>'
        from C:/Sites/spree_layered_pricing/lib/spree_layered_pricing/engine.rb:
1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_
ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_
ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
4/lib/rails/engine/commands.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_
ext/kernel_require.rb:64:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_
ext/kernel_require.rb:64:in `require'
        from script/rails:7:in `<main>'
```

Is there a way around this? What am I missing out on ?

Comment: Do you have `activerecord` gem installed?  Do `gem list activerecord` in your command prompt.  That'll give you some clue.

Comment: C:\Sites>gem list activerecord

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activerecord (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.2.12)

Comment: I did everyhting again inside a spree application, now it is working. Earlier I was doing it just outside a spree app, but inside a spree extension.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation you are referring to, just blow the migration example, they say

> TODO: Make above generator actually work in extension directories

Have you tried using a different name, then use the code they provide?

```
class AddSalePriceToSpreeVariants < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :spree_variants, :sale_price, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
  end
end
```